# How do i enable gce_persistent_disk_csi_driver_config with terraform gke module

Tags: terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp, clustering-key

I am using the Terraform GKE Module provided [here](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-google-modules/kubernetes-engine/google/latest)

I  need to enable gce_persistent_disk_csi_driver_config which is easily enabled when using google_container_cluster, like this (under the `addons_config` block)

```
gce_persistent_disk_csi_driver_config {
               enabled = false
}
```

However I cannot seem to find an equivalent of this configuration in the module gke provided in [here](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-google-modules/kubernetes-engine/google/latest)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After loking into the Go code from the github repo, I found **gce_pd_csi_driver** which is what is being used to set the flag.

```
gce_pd_csi_driver = true
```